# Approximation to $\pi(x)$ conjecture.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

A friend conjectured that $\left[\prod_{k=1}^{a_j <\sqrt{x}} \left(1-\frac{1}{a_k}\right)\right] x$ is usually closer to $\pi(x)$ than $\operatorname{Li}(x)$ is for some (fixed) sequence of integers $a_k$.

Could this be true ?

Comment: For some fixed sequence $a_k$ ? Independent of $x$ ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, that is what I meant by fixed.

Comment: Tommy1729 defined such a sequence and posted it to sci.math. if anyone is intrested.